# You can't have an association of the same name with a different target "className" option anywhere in your app

Tags: php, cakephp, permissions, cakephp-3.0

I am using **slince/cakephp-permission** package for adding permissions and roles to my CakePHP application.

I have managed to set it up but when I try to give a permission to a role I see this error:

```
Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\RolesTable association "Permissions" of type "manyToMany" to "App\Model\Table\PermissionsTable" doesn't match the expected class "Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\PermissionsTable". You can't have an association of the same name with a different target "className" option anywhere in your app.
```

The code that fire this error is the one below

```
$roleObj = Role::find($role->name);
$roleObj->givePermission($addPermission);
```

if I var_dump the $roleObj this is the result I obtain

```
object(Slince\CakePermission\Model\Entity\Role)#239 (13) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(6)
  ["name"]=>
  string(5) "Admin"
  ["slug"]=>
  string(5) "Admin"
  ["created"]=>
  object(Cake\I18n\Time)#258 (3) {
    ["time"]=>
    string(25) "2018-08-22T11:41:28+00:00"
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["fixedNowTime"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  ["modified"]=>
  string(15) "22/08/18, 11:41"
  ["[new]"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["[accessible]"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["*"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
  ["[dirty]"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[original]"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[virtual]"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[errors]"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[invalid]"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["[repository]"]=>
  string(16) "_PermissionRoles"
}
```

These are the relationship in the tables pages

```
$this->belongsToMany('Permissions', [
            'targetTable' => 'Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\Permissions',
            'className' => 'Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\Permissions',
            'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'permission_id',
            'joinTable' => 'roles_permissions',
            'saveStrategy' => 'append'
 ]);
$this->belongsToMany('Roles', [
            'targetTable' => 'Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\Roles',
            'className' => 'Slince\CakePermission\Model\Table\Roles',
            'foreignKey' => 'permission_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'role_id',
            'joinTable' => 'roles_permissions',
            'saveStrategy' => 'append'
]);
```

I have tried several different setting but I always get the same error.
I think I am missing something when setting the relations between the table up.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to repeat from zero with https://github.com/slince/cakephp-permission guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you have two (or more) associations with name "Permissions" defined within your app and each refers different model class.

You sholuld check if:

1. Any user defined associantion with name "Permissions" exists. And if so - rename it.
2. Any other plugin uses "Permissions" association (maybe legacy permissions manager) - then one must be removed or overwritten.